# Keras: Passing an array through a shared LSTM layer?

Tags: lstm, tf.keras, keras-layer

I want to construct a network with time series data, and I'm scaling up a previous problem instance.

```
# input = { sequence:list of int, time: int, score: float}
embed = Embedding(output_dim=100, input_dim=self.sequence_range + 1, mask_zero=True, name='sequence_embedding')
sq_inpt = Input(shape=(self.MAX_SEQ_LEN, 1), name='sq_inpt')
sq_embed = embed(sq_inpt)
lstm_embed = LSTM(200, go_backwards=False)(sq_embed)

time_inpt = Input(shape=(1,), name='time_inpt')
score_inpt = Input(shape=(1,), name='score_inpt')

state_embed = Concatenate()([lstm_embed, time_inpt, score_inpt])
state_embed = Dense(300, activation='elu', name='state_embed_1')(state_embed)
state_embed = Dense(300, activation='elu', name='state_embed_2')(state_embed)
output = Dense(1, name='output')(state_embed)
model = Model(inputs=[sq_inpt, time_inpt, score_inpt], outputs=output)
```

My previous network had an embedding layer on the input, which was fed into an LSTM. The output of the LSTM, along with two other numeric inputs was further fed to two Dense layers, before receiving a single unit output.

In the new version, I want to pass multiple sequences as input, each of which should independently go through the LSTM layer and then be concatenated before adding to `state_embed`.

```
# input = { sequences:list of(list of int), time: int, score: float}
embed = Embedding(output_dim=100, input_dim=self.sequence_range + 1, mask_zero=True, name='sequence_embedding')
sq_inpt = Input(shape=(self.MAX_SEQ_LEN, 1), name='sq_inpt')
sq_embed = embed(sq_inpt)

##CHANGE NEEDED HERE#######
lstm_layer = LSTM(200, go_backwards=False)

lstm_embed = []
for sequence in sq_embed:
    lstm_embed.append(lstm_layer(sequence)

###########################
.
.
.
state_embed = Concatenate()([lstm_embed, time_inpt, score_inpt])
.
.
.
model = Model(inputs=[sq_inpt, time_inpt, score_inpt], outputs=output)
```

I know the above code does not work, but it is the clearest way I could think of to represent what I want. I don't want a unique LSTM layer for each of the sequences, as I want to share the weights.

How can I implement this in Keras?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You say you want your input to be made of a list of lists of integers, instead of a list of integers, however the shape of your input in both code snippets is the same. Can you provide a reproducible code snippet for the existing NN, and an example input for the required NN?

Answer (score 0):

As you said you want your network to process multiple sequences using multiple LSTM with shared weights, however in the code you provided there is only a single sequence as input to your network. This is my proposition for two sequences for example:

```
sq_inpt1 = Input(shape=(self.MAX_SEQ_LEN, 1), name='sq_inpt1')
sq_inpt2 = Input(shape=(self.MAX_SEQ_LEN, 1), name='sq_inpt2')
sq_embd_1 = embed(sq_inpt1)
sq_embd_2 = embed(sq_input2)
lstm_layer = LSTM(200, go_backwards=False)
embd_list = [sq_embd_1,sq_emb2]
lstm_embd = []
for embd in embd_list :
    lstm_embd.append(lstm_layer(embd))
time_inpt = Input(shape=(1,), name='time_inpt')
score_inpt = Input(shape=(1,), name='score_inpt')
state_embed = Concatenate()([lstm_embed, time_inpt, score_inpt])
### Then continue the rest of the network
```

Alternatively you can use as input a single array with an expended dim (first dim for example indexes the sequence number), the script will be modified as follows:

```
sq_list = Input(shape=(self.num_seq,self.MAX_SEQ_LEN, 1), name='sq_list')
embd_list = []
for i in range(sq_list.shape[0]):
    embd_list.append(embd(sq_list[i])
lstm_layer = LSTM(200, go_backwards=False)
lstm_embd = []
for embd in embd_list :
    lstm_embd.append(lstm_layer(embd))
time_inpt = Input(shape=(1,), name='time_inpt')
score_inpt = Input(shape=(1,), name='score_inpt')
state_embed = Concatenate()([lstm_embed, time_inpt, score_inpt])
### Then continue the rest of the network
```